# Using selected object in Hibernate criteria restriction

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to rewrite a query:

```
select user from UserImpl as user where user not in (:affectedPersons)
```

With a Hibernate Criteria as:

```
createCriteria(UserImpl.class, "user").add(Restrictions.not(Restrictions.in("user", affectedPersons))));
```

But I get Hibernate exception saying:

```
'user' field is not found in UserImpl entity
```

I understand the exception but I can't find the way how to use/specify 'user' alias of selected object to make it available in criteria restriction.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here You have to give the Column/field not(Restrictions.in("user"), It will search for the field user in UserImpl , which it will not find. That is why it is giving error

Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(UserImpl.class,"user");
criteria.add(Restrictions.not(Restrictions.in("nameOfFieldInWhichYouAreStoringAffectedPersons", affectedPersons)));

Comment: Thanks for your response, but this is not a complete answer. I understand the problem of a field, but in my textual query I can state "select from UserImpl as **user**" and use that "user" for expression "**user** not in (:affectedPersons)". I am wondering how to do the same in Criteria expression as I don't have affectedPersons field in the UserImpl.